# Pandas concat(df1, df2) results to object type columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am concatenating a set of data frames read from excel.
The problem is, while the column of my interest has a float64 dtype,
the column from the concatenated data frame returns an object as the dtype.

I initially thought this would be due to missing columns in certain data frames, but did not throw a flag when I had a checker code to detect a missing column.

The code follows:
    import pandas as pd

```
for logfile in listofFiles:
  allData = pd.concat([alldata, pd.read_excel(logfile, header=0)])
```

The result I get for the concatenated data is:

```
>>allData['column_of_interest']
>> ... dtype: object
```

Whereas result for a single data frame is:

```
>> df = pd.read_excel(oneFile, header=0)
>> df['column_of_interest']
>> ... dtype: float64
```

Any wisdom would be appreciated!

Comment: Side note: it would be much faster to store all dataframes in a list and concatenate them all at the end.

Comment: If you add `print(pd.read_excel(logfile, header=0)['column_of_interest'].dtype)` in your loop, what does it say? I'm pretty sure some of them will be `object`.

Comment: try allData['column_of_interest'] = allData.column_of_interest.apply(pd.to_numeric)

Comment: Thank you Jay @IanS. Yes, there are a set of files which gets read as an object. And for those dataframse, the apply(to_numeric) throws a valueError. Digging more into the file, there seems to be some random(?) noise in the data, where one or more cells have some special characters padded to the numeric values. Will have to find a way to clean that up.

Comment: Luckily it was a '{' added to some of the cells. Removed it with `>>allData[column] = allData[column].replace(regex=True,to_replace=r'{',value='')` and then `>>allData[column] = pd.to_numeric(allData[column], 'coerce')` to convert the dtype.